# inject spring repository into static method

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I generate a list of instances which implement interface CheckInterface
using reflection, but some of those instances need to use JPA repository
,as they are new by reflection so Spring will not inject repository for them.
So how can I inject repository into these instance

Or how can I delegate these class to spring as @Bean and iterate them?

```
@Component
@Log4j
public class ValidationRegister {

public static HashMap<String, CheckItem> itemHashMap = new HashMap<>();

static {
    if (itemHashMap.size() == 0) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(CheckItem.class.getPackage().getName());
        Set<Class<? extends CheckItem>> itemClasses =
                reflections.getSubTypesOf(CheckItem.class);

        for (Class<? extends CheckItem> checkItemClass : itemClasses) {
            try {
                itemHashMap.put(checkItemClass.getName(), checkItemClass.newInstance());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("ValidationRegister fail : ", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
}

public class LPHYCZ extends CheckItem {

@Autowired
ClaimDataEntityRepository claimDataEntityRepository;

@Override
public boolean check(ClaimRequest request, List<String> errorList) {
    ClaimDataEntity claimDataEntity = claimDataEntityRepository.findByClaimId(request.getClaimId());
    if (claimDataEntity != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

> When I get instance of LPHYCZ from ValidationRegister.itemHashMap its
>   claimDataEntityRepository will be null

Comment: kindly share your code to have a better understanding

Comment: Make sure your `LPHYCZ` class is spring managed.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan LPHYCZ is managed by spring how can I iterator the class which is in the same package with LPHYCZ

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `Reflections reflections` a Spring Bean and get it injected into 'ValidationRegister' then use it to initialize your `HashMap` your hashmap still can be static, if you want it to be shared by multiple `ValidationRegister` instances, but the injection won't happen on static fields.